# "as" keyword considered confusing in TSql100Parser code

Tags: c#, t-sql, scriptdom

Suppose I want to parse the sql statement

```
SELECT foo, bar, baz FROM myTable WHERE baz = 2 ORDER BY baz ASC, bar DESC
```

and programmatically determine the columns and directions it's ordering by. After some googling, here's what I've come up with:

```
List<ParseError> Errors;
TSql100Parser parser = new TSql100Parser(true);
TSqlFragment result = parser.Parse(
    new StringReader("SELECT foo, bar, baz FROM myTable WHERE baz = 2 ORDER BY baz ASC, bar DESC"),
    out Errors);
foreach (var ts in (result as TSqlScript).Batches)
{
    foreach (var st in ts.Statements)
    {
        SelectStatement selectStatement = (SelectStatement) st;
        IList<ExpressionWithSortOrder> _list = selectStatement.QueryExpression.OrderByClause.OrderByElements;
        var c0 = _list[0].Expression as ColumnReferenceExpression;
        var c1 = _list[1].Expression as ColumnReferenceExpression;

        Assert.AreEqual("baz", c0.MultiPartIdentifier.Identifiers[0].Value);
        Assert.AreEqual("Ascending", _list[0].SortOrder.ToString());
        Assert.AreEqual("bar", c1.MultiPartIdentifier.Identifiers[0].Value);
        Assert.AreEqual("Descending", _list[1].SortOrder.ToString());
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but I find it very confusing. There are two places where the "as" keyword seems weird to me.

The first of these is on line 6. TsqlScript is a subclass of TSqlFragment, so I guess I lucked into being able to cast it to a subclass. But TSqlFragment, which is the return type of the Parse method on line 3 doesn't have any useful properties, only its subclass has useful properties. So what kind of API would expose a class that is only helpful if you happen to know to cast it to something else?

The second, and more confusing use of "as", is used in the inner foreach. How is it possible that I've turned ExpressionWithSortOrders into ColumnReferenceExpressions? They are classes, not interfaces, and they don't inherit from each other. As far as I can tell, they have neither explicit nor implicit conversion into each other.

More generally, how can one learn to work with an API like this? I haven't found anything about this casting in the official scriptdom documentation. Visual Studio doesn't tell me that I can turn these classes into each other.

Comment: `ExpressionWithSortOrder` and `ColumnReferenceExpression` both derive from `TSqlFragment`, so they are in fact related. `TSql100Parser.Parse` probably returns `TSqlFragment` because its the most derived (common) class of anything that it can parse. Its not necessarily returning `TSqlFragment`, that's just the most derived ancestor of what it is returning. The issue I have with the code is that it can easily break (`as` returns `null` if the conversion fails), the code does not check for that possibility.

Comment: Edited to clarify the difference between the two cases. In the 1st case, the two classes are related; my confusion is around why the API is structured that way. In the 2nd case my confusion is around how this could possibly compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the "first case":

MSDN states that the overload of the `Parse` method you use

> Returns a script fragment and a list of errors by using the provided
>   values. (Inherited from TSqlParser.)

So I guess that should be enough to know it is a `TSqlScript` class ;-)

Concerning the "second case":

```
    var c0 = _list[0].Expression as ColumnReferenceExpression;
    var c1 = _list[1].Expression as ColumnReferenceExpression;
```

> How is it possible that I've turned ExpressionWithSortOrders into
>   ColumnReferenceExpressions?

But you didn't. You turned the `Expression` property of the `ExpressionWithSortOrder` class into a `ColumnReferenceExpression`, which according to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.columnreferenceexpression(v=sql.120).aspx) is perfectly OK as `Expression` is of type `ScalarExpression`, and `ColumnReferenceExpression` inherits from that.

Comment: D'oh! Dopey me. Thank you.